# Flutter Riverpod - .autoDispose - The argument type 'AutoDisposeProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderBase'

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

According to [the docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose#the-argument-type-autodisposeprovider-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-alwaysaliveproviderbase) when I'm getting this error I am supposed to mark both `Providers` with `.autoDispose`:

> The argument type 'AutoDisposeProvider' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderBase'

Why am I still getting the error in this minimalistic example?

```
final a = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>((ref) {
  return Future.value(["test"]);
});

final b = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(a);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because of the `autoDispose`. If you replace the code with the following code, you'll get an error again:

```dart
// Removed "autoDispose"
final a = FutureProvider<List<String>>((ref) {
  return Future.value(["test"]);
});

final b = FutureProvider<List<String>>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(a);
});
```

The Error:

```
The argument type 'FutureProvider<List<String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<FutureOr<List<String>>>'.
```

The reason is that value of the `a` provider is an `AsyncValue` so `b` provider should returns a `AsyncValue<List<String>>` instead of `List<String>` if it return the data directly.

```dart
final a = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>((ref) {
  return Future.value(["test"]);
});

final b = FutureProvider.autoDispose<AsyncValue<List<String>>>((ref) {
 return ref.watch(a);
});
```

Or it can use the value and process it and then returns another list based on that, something like this:

```dart
final a = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>((ref) {
  return Future.value(["test"]);
});

final b = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<String>>((ref) async {
  final value = ref.watch(a);

  // Doing another operation
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

  return value.maybeWhen(
    data: (data) => data.map((e) => 'B $e').toList(),
    orElse: () => [],
  );
});
```

Answer (score 11):

This error is happening because you tried to listen to a provider marked with .autoDispose in a provider that is not marked with .autoDispose.

```
final firstProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) => 0);

final secondProvider = Provider((ref) {
  // The argument type 'AutoDisposeProvider<int>' can't be assigned to the
  // parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderBase<Object, Null>'
  ref.watch(firstProvider);
});
```

The solution is marking the secondProvider with .autoDispose.

```
final firstProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) => 0);

final secondProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) {
  ref.watch(firstProvider);
});
```

I just copy the solution from the official Riverpod documentation at the bottom of the page:
https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose/